# How to login sitecore User using Active directory credentials

Tags: sitecore-client, login, active-directory-module

when the CM link is browsed users should be automatically logged in to the CMS.How do i do this ?which pipeline should i over ride .

Comment: Have you followed the documentation for the Active Directory module? Follow this link to get you to the right version for your installation. https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Active_Directory/ There are other questions posted here on Stack Exchange that may help you get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore's AD Module provides functionality to allow users to perform Single Sign-on to the Sitecore client using their Active Directory accounts. As the users land at URL /sitecore/admin/ldaplogin.aspx it will authenticate them.

You can read more about how to configure LDAP login as the default login at http://www.nehemiahj.com/2013/01/how-to-enable-single-sign-on-in-sitecore.html

Alternatively you can set your CM domain default page as /sitecore/admin/ldaplogin.aspx.